# How to remove loader GIF after image load with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone tell me why I'm unable to detect the load event on this image element and set the loading GIF to `display: none`? I'd like to set the div with the loader class to `display: none` when the first image loads after the `Add Image` button is clicked. Right now it only sets the style after I click the Add Doggo button twice.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
    <title>image loader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dog Images</h1>
    <button class="add-doggo">Add Image</button>
    <div class="doggos">
        <div class="loader"><img src="src/Preloader.gif" /></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/doggos.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.loader {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const DOG_URL = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random';

const doggos = document.querySelector('.doggos');
let loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

let dogImage, isLoaded;

function addNewDoggo() {
    const promise = fetch(DOG_URL);
    promise

        .then(function (response) {
            const processingPromise = response.json(); //This line of code parses the API response into a usuable js object
            return processingPromise; //this code returns a new promise and this process is called | PROCESS-CHAINING
        })
        .then(function (processedResponse) {
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.classList.add('dog-image');
            img.src = processedResponse.message;
            img.alt = 'Cute doggo';
            doggos.appendChild(img);
        });
}

document.querySelector('.add-doggo').addEventListener('click', () => {
    dogImage = document.querySelector('.dog-image');
    isLoaded = dogImage?.complete && dogImage?.naturalHeight !== 0;
    if (!isLoaded) {
        loader.style.display = 'block';
        console.log(true);
    } else if (isLoaded) {
        loader.style.display = 'none';
        console.log('IMAGE LOADED');
    }
    return addNewDoggo();
});

// Adding event listener on the image element itself to detect if it's loaded
document.querySelector('.dog-image').addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('DOG IMAGE LOADED');
    isLoaded = dogImage?.complete && dogImage?.naturalHeight !== 0;
    if (isLoaded) {
        loader.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: The last thing you code appears to do is add a load event listener. How do you know the image isn't already finished at this point? Typically, one adds a listener to the image, *then* one gives the image a src. That way, you cannot apply the listener after it's already loaded. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, as mentioned in a comment, you can clearly see that the first thing I do with the newly created image element is to give it an event handler for the load event. That's really all there is to it AFAIK.

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function qsa(sel,parent=document){return parent.querySelectorAll(sel)}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    qsa('button')[0].addEventListener('click', addNewDog, false);
}

const dogUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random";

function addNewDog()
{
    qsa('.loader')[0].classList.remove('hidden');
    fetch(dogUrl)
        .then( response => response.json() )
        .then( jsObj =>  {
                    let img = newEl('img');
                    img.addEventListener('load', onUserImgLoaded, false);
                    img.classList.add('dog-image');
                    img.alt = 'cute dog';
                    img.src = jsObj.message;
                    qsa('.doggos')[0].appendChild(img);
                }
            );
}

function onUserImgLoaded(evt)
{
    qsa('.loader')[0].classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
.loader img
{
    max-width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dog Images</h1>
    <button class="add-doggo">Add Image</button>
    <div class="doggos">
        <div class="loader hidden"><img src="https://flevix.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Bounce-Bar-Preloader-1.gif" /></div>
    </div>
```